# How to convert an XML file produced by RSS feed to a file in Atom format?

Tags: xml, rss, file-conversion, atom-feed

I have an XML file (obviously) which is the output of an RSS feed. I would like to convert that file to the Atom format.

There are plenty of Q&A's on StackOverflow [about converting *feeds*](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=rss+atom+xml+convert), but I want to convert a *file*.

I expect this is going to involve XSLT, but that is beyond me, and it's possible that such a converter already exists. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little more looking turned up an XSLT file from 2003 that seems to do the trick.

Original is at [iBLOGthere4iM](http://www.ibt4im.com/?guid=20031218172501), or a conveniently saved [gist](https://gist.github.com/2844457), if anyone is interested.